# cannot display successful or error message after submitting the form without refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to create a email contact form without refreshing the page. so i used jquery for that. Now after submitting the form i want to send successful or error message to the user. Here is my code:

index.html

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>HTML5 Contact Form</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="styles.css" >
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mycontactform').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("contact.php", $(this).serialize(), function(response) {   
            $('#success').html(response);
            //$('#success').hide('slow');
        });
    });
});        
        </script>

        </head>
        <body>


        <form id="mycontactform" class="contact_form" action="" method="post" name="contact_form">
            <ul>
                <li>
                     <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                     <span class="required_notification">* Denotes Required Field</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text"  id="name"  name="name" placeholder="John Doe" required />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="john_doe@example.com" required />
                    <span class="form_hint">Proper format "name@something.com"</span>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="message">Message:</label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message"  cols="40" rows="6" required ></textarea>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button class="submit"  id="submit"  style="cursor:pointer" type="submit">Submit Form</button>

                    <div id="success" style="color:red;"></div>



                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>

        </body>
        </html>
```

contact.php

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['name'];
$field_email = $_POST['email'];
$field_message = $_POST['message'];

$mail_to = 'babloopuneeth@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { 

    echo "Your email was sent!";
} else {
    echo "Your email was not sent!";
}
?>
```

Now after submitting the form, if the mail was sent successfully i want if statement of php to be displayed if mail was not sent i wand else statment to be executed. But Im not getting successful or error messages after submitting the form nor im recieving any mail? Where am i going wrong? And is my jquery code correct to submit the form without refreshing the page? Plz someone help me

Comment: Check the javascript console and network tab in your browser for errors.

Comment: You will need to use javascript to submit it, read the mesage and display it to the user. Try searching AJAX

Comment: It looks like the javascript lines `return false;` and the two `});` below shouldn't be there, and might be causing a script error.

Comment: @JasonP: That brackets is to close the first two functions

Comment: @PuneethP I disagree. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/AxQdZ/. If you look at the javascript console, you can see the error.

Comment: @JasonP: I edited the code. Even it is not working

Comment: As I said in my first comment, check your javascript console for errors (which I know you didn't do, or you would have seen the syntax error) and check the network tab for errors and to make sure your ajax calling is returning what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the data to a different page. You need to pass the message you wish to display back to the originating page before it will display. You can do this using jQuery.

You can have a div on your page as a place holder

```
<div id="message"></div>
```

Then load the output of contact.php into it

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i actually didnt get you fully. Can yyou help me with the code?